# Add headings to simple cursor adaptor data in android

Tags: android, list, cursor

I'm binding data from a cursor to a list as shown below;

```
    db.open();

Cursor c = db.getAllRowsCursor();
    c.moveToFirst();

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, // Context.
            R.layout.custom_row_view,  
            c,                                              
            new String[] {"name", "distance", "time"},            
            new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3});  

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
```

This works fine but it only shows the data. What is the best way to add headings to the data?

For example I want the list to read

```
Name: <name data>
Distance: <distance data>
Time: <time data>
```

rather than just;

```
<name data>
<distance data>
<time data>
```

I hope its clear what I'm trying to achieve here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend SimpleCursorAdapter and override method `bindView  (View  view, Context  context, Cursor  cursor)`
Here `view` - is a your `R.layout.custom_row_view`.
Cursor - your cursor which already moved to correct position
You need manually get Strings from cursor, get TextViews from view, add headings and set correct text to TextViews

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
  String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
  s = "Name:" + s;
  TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
  tv.setText(s);
}
```